# Storing Bitmap for multiple Activities?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-activity

I'm looking for a way to store some Bitmaps that can be accessed by multiple activities, without having to be reloaded from the web.

I do NOT want to simply pass them from Activity to Activity by putting them into an `Intent`, but rather have one place where I can access them without having to pass them.

I looked into caching to help solve this problem, but if this is the solution I'm a little unclear as to how to make the cache accesible in multiple activities.

Any suggestions or alternative solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tell us something you have tried so far.

Comment: that's a very complex thing to achieve and for beginners the best approach is just use a library like @yakiv.mospan suggested like Picasso. edit: to be honest even for non beginners, why bother writing it all again if there're such good open sources freely available libraries?

Comment: @Budius My hesitation with using Picasso is that I will have to re-download the image each time I need it in a different activity.

Comment: Mo you won't. Picasso already caches the images both in RAM and Disk. From http://square.github.io/picasso/  `Automatic memory and disk caching.` It's the 5th line on the site, just a bit read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html), a library such as [Volley](https://developers.google.com/live/shows/474338138), or implement the same functionality yourself. I think that the volley library would be perfect for you.

To access it from anywhere in your application you should either store it in a special application object or in a static variable. Note that only a reference to the cache will be stored there. The size of the cache is in both cases listed above configurable.

Comment: ablut the LruCache, it should be noted that even though it's not supported on older devices, it's rather easy to copy the code and make it work on older APIs...

Answer (score 0):

What does `the cache accesible in multiple activities` means ? Just dowload it from web, save to SD card (chache it) and then load it from SD card from as many Activities as you want.

[Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal) are some example of how you can store data in Android.

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) loader for this task.

Comment: Yes for sure. Picasso library get bitmap name depanding on url that you gave it. If the answer was right please accept it. Thank's

Comment: You also can go throw this tutorials  developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html. Thay will help you alot.

Comment: thank you for your solution! I'm a little concerned about two things. The first is the time it will take to load the data from the SD card. I'm hoping to find a solution that allows the images to be loaded and rendered quickly. The second concern is the space these Images will be taking up on the SD card. Will the files be permanent? or rather just temporary until more memory is needed.

Comment: Loading images from SD isn't very slow (look on your gallery app for example). About memmory - I've provided url about storing data in Android you can find some answer there. If you decided to use Picasso you need to look throw their docs. I'm not sure but I think thay have different ways to store/clear chache.

Answer (score -1):

You can make static array or map of bitmaps and access it from where u want.
If there are a lot of images you can also make queue and store only most recent used there.

Comment: As I said it depend on number of images, if the number is higher - queue will help a lot, cos we will keep only most recent used and other can be stored on sd card or downloaded again

Comment: From here http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html:

Bitmaps take up a lot of memory, especially for rich images like photographs. For example, the camera on the Galaxy Nexus takes photos up to 2592x1936 pixels (5 megapixels). If the bitmap configuration used is ARGB_8888 (the default from the Android 2.3 onward) then loading this image into memory takes about 19MB of memory (2592*1936*4 bytes), immediately exhausting the per-app limit on some devices.

Comment: Yakiv, when loading such big bitmaps you should load them downscaled to fit the resolution you are going to display. If you are zooming you should crop. If I'm correctly informed the Volley library mentioned in my post helps you with that.

Comment: Tobias, This comments was direccted to "Storing Bitmaps in static array" theme. For sure thay need to be scaled. Wasn't using Volley yet, still using own REST client.

Comment: Actually you can try static arrays or queue and you will see how little memory is used. Of course u are not going to store 19MB bitmaps there. It is more than obvious that they should be scaled a lot. Can't understand why u disagree.